# Performing math on 2 fields on my modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

how can I perform math when a user enters digits within my modal popup?  I have 2 fields 1 of which is populated by the datepicker (min nubeer of days) the second is filled in by the user.  I need the price per day field * (multiplied) by the min number of days to give a total price for the period.

I would like it on the area of dialog I have put an arrow too, how would I start to do this please? I'm sure its really easy and I know the php file concerned but I dont know how to add text to that dialog box.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="coment"><?php echo esc_html__( 'New Price in ','wprentals').' '.esc_html($wp_estate_currency_symbol);?></label>
                        <input type="text" id="new_custom_price" size="40" name="new_custom_price" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="period_min_days_booking"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Minimum days of booking','wprentals');?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="period_min_days_booking" size="40" name="period_min_days_booking" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Define an event on user input and get values by jQuery and perform math action.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#new_custom_price', function() {
    var newCustomPrice = Number($('#new_custom_price').val());
    var periodMinDaysBooking = Number($('#period_min_days_booking').val());
    var result = newCustomPrice * periodMinDaysBooking;
    // Do anything with result
    console.log(result)
})
```